# React native clear Stack Navigator stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have few screens which I navigate through one by one. Screen1->screen2-screen3->screen4-Home

What I want is when I go to home then the previous history of navigation should be cleared and back pressing back button should not go to last navigated screen which is screen 4. Currently When I press back button on home screen it takes me back to the last route in the stack which is screen4. I have used below code. It is giving me error no route defined or key Home. Which I have already defined in Screens class. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,                       
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
});

onPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)}
```

Comment: Refer to the accepted answer here for updated information as of today . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443451/undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-reactnavigation-navigationactions-reset

Answer (score 57):

in V5, you can use

```
this.props.navigation.reset({
              index: 0,
              routes: [{name: 'Home'}],
            });
```

Using hooks

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const navigation = useNavigation();

navigation.reset({
        index: 0,
        routes: [{name: 'Events'}],
      });
```

Answer (score 10):

As it states in the [react-navigation docs for reset action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#How-to-use-the-index-parameter), index should be the current active route's index. The error might be related to that.

> **How to use the index parameter**
>
> The index param is used to specify the
>   current active route. eg: given a basic stack navigation with two
>   routes Profile and Settings. To reset the state to a point where the
>   active screen was Settings but have it stacked on top of a Profile
>   screen, you would do the following:

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile'}),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Settings'})
  ]
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Comment: How to get the current index?

Comment: @ParasWatts You can use [Screen Tracking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/screen-tracking#Screen-tracking) functionality to get current state and the index of the route.

Comment: @bennygenel link broken, is https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html same ?

Answer (score 7):

```
import {NavigationActions} from 'react-navigation';                
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HomeScreen'})
    ] })
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

you can use this, this works for me..

Answer (score 5):

If you use **react-navigation@<=4** you can use a Switch Navigator.

You create a Switch Navigator with `createSwitchNavigator`.
Such navigators do not stack up your navigation.
Add your auth screen/navigator in a  Switch Navigator with the home screen/stack.

With that, when you navigate from home to log in, the stacks are not kept.

For more on it:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/auth-flow/

Comment: It was not available earlier

Comment: Not available in Version 5

Answer (score 5):

With `@react-navigation 5.x` you can use `CommonActions` to reset/clear the stack. I'll leave an example here.

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const handleSigninNavigation = () => {
 navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ name: "your-new-route" }]
  }));
}
```

Also you can create your own stack while resetting it. Just pass the names of the routes to routes array and give an index to navigate first.

```
CommonActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  routes: [{ name: "home" }, { name: "signin" }]
}));
```

Above code will reset the current stack with given routes and will navigate to the `signin` since we set the index to 1.

Answer (score 1):

With typed routes and their parameters

```
type StateRoute<Route extends keyof MyNavigatorParamList> = {
  name: Route;
  params: MyNavigatorParamList[Route];
};

const toNavigationStateRoutes = <Route extends keyof MyNavigatorParamList>(
  ...routes: StateRoute<Route>[]
) => routes;

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 1,
    routes: toNavigationStateRoutes(
      {
        name: 'Home',
        params: undefined,
      },
      {
        name: 'Some screen',
        params: { id: "..." },
      },
    ),
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

//import

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
```

//reset current navigation stack and create new navigation stack

```
const loginScreenAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,                       
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoginScreen' })],
});
```

//open new component with new navigation stack

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(loginScreenAction)
```